# PHP; encode and decode functions produce the same output

Tags: php, sanitization

Sanitising some user input;

```
function html_mysql_sanitise($data) {
  if(get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    $data = stripslashes($data);
  }
  $data = htmlentities($data, ENT_QUOTES);
  $data = htmlspecialchars($data, ENT_QUOTES);
  return mysql_real_escape_string($data);
}

$_POST['data'] = html_mysql_sanitise($_POST['data']);

echo $_POST['data'];
echo html_entity_decode(htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['data']));
echo html_entity_decode($_POST['data'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($_POST['data'], ENT_NOQUOTES);
```

$_POST['data'] is set to;

```
test<d#'!;ta>
```

The output of this is;

```
test&lt;d#&#039;!;ta&gt;
test
test<d#'!;ta>
test<d#'!;ta>
```

Why do the last two produce the same result, and the 2nd one is part of the posted data? Since the last two seem to produce the desired result, which should I use?

Thank you.

Comment: was the `'` submitted as `&quot;`? If it's just a real `'`, then decoding will not change it.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Thanks for the info Madara, some very useful links, I shall be updating this code ASAP! Thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why re-invent the wheel... use this:

http://htmlpurifier.org/docs

Or this:

http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/index.php

Both good at exactly what you want to do.

Comment: These are great, thanks very much for the links! Just what I needed and much more powerful

Comment: and I would combine it with the comments from @MadaraUchiha regarding the mysql_ functions. PDO is the best way forward too - as per his arguments, while you're app is perhaps at a stage to change such stuff